# Can Drone be run in a platform agnostic way (like a manual webhook mode)?

Tags: drone.io

When trying to setup Drone, the getting started guides all describe how to link Drone with an existing git service provider (like GitHub, BitBucket, etc).

The integration is tight, all your repositories are available and it's a zero config setup to attach a pipeline to a repository.

I would like to use Drone in a less opinionated way, where I run the Drone server and set up the runners without any git integration.

I would like to be able to navigate to the dashboard, add and name a new pipeline then set up the webhooks/triggers with the git service host manually.

Authentication would be via standard ssh keys and it's all very simple from there.

Currently, attempting to run Drone without an integration specified causes it to fail to launch.

Is it possible to use Drone this way or do I have to fork out for something like Buildkite?

Answer (score 0):

Drone is pretty tightly coupled to the git provider - it makes use of the git provider for authentication and as a source of truth for repos.

The drone server and individual runners code is all open source - so you can fork it :) - [Drone github repo](https://github.com/harness/drone)

Comment: I actually considered forking Drone but I don't want to have to keep tracking updates. I'm surprised they didn't start off with a decoupled implementation that fires off webhooks then later layer on top of that easy-setup integrations with the various git providers.

The current implementation makes things like migrations from one git provider to another very challenging.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was asked back in Feb, 2017 in [Drone forum](https://community.harness.io/). I am citing the answer below.

[Link to the question](https://community.harness.io/t/multiple-git-repo-providers/10874).

> It is not possible. If you would like to use Drone with GitHub and GitLab, you need to run two instances of the Drone server.